# yarn add nested local package

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I have a local package, say A, which contains three local subpackages a, b and c. b depends on a. c depends on both a and b. What I wanna do is to add package c as a dependency for another local Package B. What is the right way to do it? The structure can be described as:

```
A/
  package.json
  a/
   package.json
  b/
   package.json
  c/
   package.json
```

A is managed by Yarn workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Add c to `dependencies` in the package.json for b like so:

```
"dependencies": {
  "c": "1.0.0",
},
```

See https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces#toc-how-to-use-it